# Laravel array format collection

Tags: arrays, string, variables, laravel, controller

I have database output like

`[{"lessonTypeId":"1"},{"lessonTypeId":"2"}]`

how i can only displey values like

`[(1,2)]`

in contorller.

Answer (score 0):

Use [pluck](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-pluck) method.

```
$ids = $result->pluck('lessonTypeId');
```